# Gson Serialize field only if not null or not empty

Tags: java, json, serialization, groovy, gson

I have requirement where I need to convert java object to json.

I am using Gson for that but i need the converter to only serialize the non null or not empty values.

For example:

```
//my java object looks like
class TestObject{
    String test1;
    String test2;
    OtherObject otherObject = new OtherObject();
}
```

now my Gson instance to convert this object to json looks like

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
TestObject obj = new TestObject();
obj.test1 = "test1";
obj.test2 = "";

String jsonStr = gson.toJson(obj);
println jsonStr;
```

In the above print, the result is

```
{"test1":"test1", "test2":"", "otherObject":{}}
```

Here i just wanted the result to be

```
{"test1":"test1"}
```

Since the test2 is empty and otherObject is empty, i don't want them to be serialized to json data.

Btw, I am using Groovy/Grails so if there is any plugin for this that would be good, if not any suggestion to customize the gson serialization class would be good.

Comment: How does it know the `otherObject` is empty?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create your own `TypeAdapter`

```
public class MyTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<TestObject>() {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, TestObject value) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value.test1)) {
            out.name("test1");
            out.value(value.test1);
        }

        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value.test2)) {
            out.name("test2");
            out.value(value.test1);
        }
        /* similar check for otherObject */         
        out.endObject();    
    }

    @Override
    public TestObject read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // do something similar, but the other way around
    }
}
```

You can then register it with `Gson`.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(TestObject.class, new MyTypeAdapter()).create();
TestObject obj = new TestObject();
obj.test1 = "test1";
obj.test2 = "";
System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
```

produces

```
 {"test1":"test1"}
```

The `GsonBuilder` class has a bunch of methods to create your own serialization/deserialization strategies, register type adapters, and set other parameters.

`Strings` is a Guava class. You can do your own check if you don't want that dependency.

Comment: what if I have other different objects on my TestObject class. for ex: generally my class will have multiple embedded objects of different type

Comment: @zdesam You do the nested serialization in this class. This class is completely dependent on your `TestObject` class so it is best suited to do all its serialization/deserialization. No other component can check the custom conditions you want.

Comment: With having such to be omitted empty strings in neatly every class, your solution boils down to doing everything manually. Even serializing all fields needing no special handling. There isn't much of what Gson does left.

Comment: downvoted because of if elses' - using reflections is a better approach ignoring the need for T

Comment: @Clocker It's not feasible to do it with reflection, recursively. How do you describe that `OtherObject` is empty? It has no fields? It has no fields that are non empty (recursively with these same rules)? It has no fields that are null? It has no fields that have a default value? Does this apply to all Pojo types or just `OtherObject`? With a type adapter, you're being explicit for the types you're responsible for.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis did you see Stan's answer below? Not sure about the recursion part or where that came from.

Comment: @Clocker It's easy to define generic logic for `String`, array types and `Collection` types, all you do is cast to the corresponding type and check if they are empty (with whatever definition of empty you choose). But how do you do that for a POJO like the `OtherObject` in the OP? You have to apply these emptiness rules to fields of that `OtherObject`. What if that class has fields that are also POJO types? You have to recur. This becomes more complicated if you have circular references.

Comment: @Clocker Then you have to consider that not all POJO types are equal in their definition of emptiness. Creating an adapter for each (or for set of them) allows you to be explicit and I think that's more useful than some attempt at writing all these rules generically with reflection.

Answer (score 10):

What I personally don't like in `TypeAdapter` using answer is the fact you need to describe every field of your entire class which could have lets say 50 fields (which means 50 `if` blocks in `TypeAdapter`).
My solution is based on `Reflection` and a fact `Gson` will not serialize null values fields by default.
I have a special class which holds data for API to create document called DocumentModel, which has about 50 fields and I don't like to send `String` fields with "" (empty but not null) values or empty arrays to server. So I created a special method which returns me a copy of my object with all empty fields nulled. Note - by default all arrays in my DocumentModel instance are initialized as empty (zero length) arrays and thus they are never null, you should probably check your arrays for null before checking their length.

```
public DocumentModel getSerializableCopy() {
    Field fields[] = new Field[]{};
    try {
        // returns the array of Field objects representing the public fields
        fields = DocumentModel.class.getDeclaredFields();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DocumentModel copy = new DocumentModel();
    Object value;
    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            value = field.get(this);
            if (value instanceof String && TextUtils.isEmpty((String) value)) {
                field.set(copy, null);
            // note: here array is not being checked for null!
            else if (value instanceof Object[] && ((Object[]) value).length == 0) {
                field.set(copy, null);
            } else
                field.set(copy, value);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Using this method I don't care if some fields was added or removed after this method was written or whatever. The only problem left - is checking custom type fields, which are not `String` or array, but this depends to particular class and should be extra coded in if/else blocks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me the problem is not with gson.  Gson correctly keeps track of the difference between null and an empty string.  Are you sure you want to erase that distinction?  Are you sure all classes that use TestObject don't care?

What you could do if you don't care about the difference is to change the empty strings to null within a TestObject before serializing it.  Or better, make the setters in TestObject such that an empty string is set to null; that way you define rigidly within the class that an empty string is the same as null.  You'll have to make sure the values cannot be set outside the setters.

Comment: Good point, but often you don't want to use both `""` and `null`. The saner solution is probably avoiding `null` and using `""` only.  Other libraries could work better with empty strings than with nulls. *Databases can enforce NOT NULL but they can't enforce "not empty".* +++ Normalizing to nulls is not an option for me as my objects are at the point still attached to a Hibernate session.

Answer (score 0):

**I have ran into the same problem and found 2 distinct solutions**

---

1. **Write a custom TypeAdapter for each field class**

TypeAdapter example for String class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class JSONStringAdapter extends TypeAdapter {

    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
            
        String value = jsonReader.nextString();
        if(value == null || value.trim().length() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object object) throws IOException {
    
        String value = String.valueOf(object);
        if(value == null || value.trim().length() == 0) {    
            jsonWriter.nullValue();
        } else {
            jsonWriter.value(value);
       }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
public class Doggo {

    @JsonAdapter(JSONStringAdapter.class)
    private String name;

    public Doggo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doggo aDoggo = new Doggo("");
        String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(aDoggo);
    }
}
```

---

2. **Process the object manually before generating the JSON string**

Seems to work on anything, haven't tested the performance:

```
public static boolean removeEmpty(JSONObject source) {
    
    if (null == source || source.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    boolean isJsonObjectEmpty = false; 

    for (String key : JSONObject.getNames(source)) {
        Object value = source.get(key);
        
        boolean isValueEmpty = isValueEmpty(value);
        if(isValueEmpty) {
            source.remove(key);
        }
    }
    
    if(source.length() == 0) {
        isJsonObjectEmpty = true;
    }
    
    return isJsonObjectEmpty;
}

private static boolean isValueEmpty(Object value) {

    if (null == value) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
        
        JSONArray arr =  (JSONArray) value;
        if(arr.length() > 0) {
            
            List<Integer> indextesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
                
                boolean isValueEmpty = isValueEmpty(arr.get(i));
                if(isValueEmpty) {
                    indextesToRemove.add(i);
                };
            }
            
            for(Integer index : indextesToRemove) {
                arr.remove(index);
            }
            
            if(arr.length() == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        
    } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
    
        return removeEmpty((JSONObject) value);
         
    } else {
        
        if (JSONObject.NULL.equals(value) 
            || null == value 
            || value.toString().trim().length() == 0)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Use:

```
public class Doggo {

    private String name;

    public Doggo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doggo aDoggo = new Doggo("");
        
        // if you are not using Type Adapters for your fields
        JSONObject aJSONObject1 = new JSONObject(aDoggo);
        removeEmpty(aJSONObject1);
        String jsonString1 = aJSONObject1.toString();

        // if you are using Type Adapters for your fields
        Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
        JSONObject aJSONObject2 = new JSONObject(gsonParser .toJson(aDoggo));
        removeEmpty(aJSONObject2);
        String jsonString2 = aJSONObject2.toString();
    }
}
```