# Gson serialization depending on field value

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I have a POJO that is similar to:

```
public class MyGsonPojo {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("value1")
    private String valueOne;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("value2")
    private boolean valueTwo;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("value3")
    private int valueThree;

    // Getters and other stuff here
}
```

The issue is that this object has to be serialized into a json body for a call
to the server. Some fields are optional for the request and if I even send it with default and null values, the API responds differently (Unfortunately changing the api is not an option).

So basically I need to exclude fields from serialization if any of them is set to a default value. For example if the field `valueOne` is `null` the resulting json should be:

```
{
    "value2" : true,
    "value3" : 2
}
```

Any idea how to make this a painless effort? I wouldn't want to build the json body manually.

Any help would be great. Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Steps to follow:

- Convert the JSON String into `Map<String,Object>` using [Gson#fromJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- Iterate the map and remove the entry from the map which are `null`
- Form the JSON String back from the final map using [Gson#toJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29).

I have already posted the sample code in the same context here:

- [Remove empty collections from a JSON with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920740/remove-empty-collections-from-a-json-with-gson?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

Option 1) Use a TypeAdapter, see accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491733/gson-serialize-field-only-if-not-null-or-not-empty):

Option 2) If using [Jackson](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://jackson.codehaus.org/&ei=vC-SU42tNpWnyASP6oHIAg&usg=AFQjCNEVenmX5WpDaLAxyQRjqVpvRP8g_A&sig2=KFfJ_m-RS-ihcQEngu3blQ) instead of gson is a possibility, you can annotate/serialize on  getters instead of on fields, and put your logic for returning
whatever you need for "default values" in your getters.

```
//won't get serialized because it's private 
private String valueOne;
...
@JsonSerialize
String getValueOne(){
   if (valueOne == null) return "true"
   else...
}
```

You could also use a single `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` annotation at the top of your class to prevent any null or empty fields from being serialized.

Comment: Thx, for your answer. Unfortunately Jackson is not an option (to many objects to refactor). And TypeAdapter can be excluded if the object has like 10 or even 15 fields.

Comment: @SerjLotutovici What do you mean "can be excluded"?

Comment: "Can be excluded" as a solution. I don't imagine any one who would try to write a TypeAdapter for an object with 15 fields - to many chances that you will make a mistake. But thx for the Jackson tip - will consider it in my next project.

Comment: Ah, well yes I'd agree with you there, if that's the case. I'd look at @Braj's first solution