# Retrofit: Update only specific fields

Tags: rest, parse-platform, gson, retrofit

I've been trying out [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and I really it's simplicity.

However I have an otimization concern.
I'm using [Parse](http://www.parse.com) for my backend and it has a pure Rest API.

When I want to update an object I use a `PUT HTTP Request` and pass in the `body` only the specific values I want to update.

However, using Retrofit I always have to serialize the entire object when passing it using the `@Body` annotation. If I have a very large object, this is very inneficient.

All the solutions I see is using Annotations to inform the Converter which fields are exposed. However this affects all requests and won't work if I have different update methods for updating different fields.

I think I have two options:

1. Pass the parameters I want to update as `Form` parameters and use
   the `@URLEncoded` annotation. However this is not really `RESTful`
   and I don't think `Parse` supports it.
2. Create an annotation to inform which fields should be added to `JSON` in the `body`. For doing this, how can I access the method's annotations in the Converter, in order to select which fields to serialize?

Comment: You could have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491733/gson-serialize-field-only-if-not-null-or-not-empty and the respective answers. Would that help?

Comment: Sort of. But inside the Converter, how would I now which fields does the user want to serialize? I could create an annotation in the specific service method, but inside the GsonConverter how can I access this annoation?

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit uses Gson by default. And Gson excludes null values by default. So  it shouldn't be a problem (unless you are using primitive types in your object)

Comment: That is not what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to choose which fields from an object to send in the body request. All solutions I've seen are through annotations, however that impacts all requests with the same object.

Comment: If you create a new object and set just the fields that you are interested in, all the other fields will be null, not serialized by Gson and will not be sent in the body

Comment: @ffleandro I tried with both PUT and PATCH (which I use for update) and after looking at the request in charles proxy I can confirm that only the initialized fields are being sent

Comment: I understand that, but I want to filter specific fields, not only the initialized. For instance I want to send fields `a` and `c` on a request, and only `a` and `b` on another request of the same endpoint.

Comment: How about primitive fields? How can you exclude them from the body?

Comment: @Stan you can register TypeAdapters with Gson. Have a look here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter