# Can we replace the annotation @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) which is from JACKSON to their counterpart in GSON

Tags: java, jackson, gson, converters

Can we replace the annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` which is from JACKSON to their counterpart annotation in GSON?
Can we replace the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` which is from JACKSON to their counterpart annotation in GSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson Serialize field only if not null or not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491733/gson-serialize-field-only-if-not-null-or-not-empty)

Comment: @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true any idea for this one?